# How do i side load NPM dependencies into HANA WebIDE?

Tags: node.js, hana, sap-web-ide

I am working in HANA WebIDE. I've checked out a project from git and tried building it. The build fails due to dependencies not being available. There is not command line to run NPM commands. Is there a way to "side-load" NPM dependencies and make them available for my project?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to configure a different NPM registry.

If you are using the build tools included in SAP Web IDE for SAP HANA to build your Node.js applications for XS advanced, you can configure SAP Web IDE for SAP HANA to use one or more specific NPM registries to resolve the dependencies between the resources specified in the development and deployment descriptors.

To specify a specific NPM registry that will be used for the resolution of dependency requirements when developing and building applications with SAP Web IDE for SAP HANA, add the "UPSTREAM_LINK" property to the di-local-npm-registry module in the MTA extension descriptor (for example, sapwebide.mtaext) that is used when deploying SAP Web IDE, as illustrated in the following example:

```
...
modules:
  - name: di-local-npm-registry
    properties:
      UPSTREAM_LINK: "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
      SAPUPSTREAM_LINK: "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
...
```

You can find more information in the [SAP HANA Developer Guide for SAP HANA XS Advanced Model](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/726e5d41462c4eb29eaa6cc83ff41e84.html#loio726e5d41462c4eb29eaa6cc83ff41e84__section_bmv_5kg_vz).